# CUDA: Pointer to intermediate shared memory location unexpected behavior

Tags: memory, cuda, global

I am launching a kernel with linear blocks of 512 threads. Associated with each thread are six double precision values (two 3-element vectors) that I would like to store in shared memory, for a total of 512*6*8=24576 bytes. I would like to create pointers to the intermediate elements of shared to line all the vectors up as follows:

```
__global__ void my_kernel(double *global_data) {
    extern __shared__ double shr[];

    id = threadIdx.x;
    double *X = &shr[id*3];
    double *Y = &shr[(id+1)*3];
    // Some arithmetic to set X[0:3] ad Y[0:3]
    // Now I have a small for loop to compute something for each thread       

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j < 3; j++) {
            // Some computations involving the X and Y vectors
    }
}
```

My problem is with accessing the values in X and Y using the looping indices. I am unable to explain the following behavior during the first loop iteration:

```
(cuda-gdb) cuda thread
thread (0,0,0)
(cuda-gdb) p shr[0]
$1 = 0.62293193093894383
(cuda-gdb) p &shr[0]
$2 = (@shared double *) 0x0
(cuda-gdb) p X[0]
$3 = 0.62293193093894383 
(cuda-gdb) p &X[0]
$4 = (@generic double *) 0x1000000
(cuda-gdb) p X
$5 = (@generic double * @register) 0x1000000
```

I think this is normal. But then:

```
(cuda-gdb) p i == 0
$7 = true
(cuda-gdb) p X[i]
Error: Failed to read global memory at address 0x0 on device 0 sm 0 warp 0 lane 0 (error=7).
```

Why is it that when i == 0 I can access X[0] but not X[i]?

EDIT: Here is a complete working example demonstrating my issue:

```
import pycuda.gpuarray as gpuarray
import pycuda.driver as cuda
import pycuda.autoinit
import numpy as np
from pycuda.compiler import SourceModule
from math import pi

mydat = np.arange(12).astype(np.float64)
mydat_gpu = gpuarray.to_gpu(mydat)

mod = SourceModule("""
__global__ void my_kernel(double *mydat) {
        extern __shared__ double shr[];
        int id = threadIdx.x;

        double *X = &shr[(id * 6)];
        double *Y = &shr[(id * 6) + 3];

        X[0] = mydat[0];
        X[1] = mydat[1];        
        X[2] = mydat[2];        
        Y[0] = mydat[3];
        Y[1] = mydat[4];
        Y[2] = mydat[5];


        __syncthreads();        

        double result;

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                result += X[i] + Y[i];
        }
}
""")

my_kernel = mod.get_function("my_kernel")
blk = (1,1,1)
grd = (1,1,1)

my_kernel(mydat_gpu, grid=grd, block=blk, shared=(8*6))
```

At this point I start up a debugging session:

```
cuda-gdb --args python -m pycuda.debug minimal_working_example.py

(cuda-gdb) b my_kernel
Function "my_kernel" not defined.
Make breakpoint pending on future shared library load? (y or [n]) y

Breakpoint 1 (my_kernel) pending.
(cuda-gdb) run

[Switching focus to CUDA kernel 0, grid 1, block (0,0,0), thread (0,0,0), device 0, sm 0, warp 0, lane 0]

Breakpoint 1, my_kernel(double * @generic)<<<(1,1,1),(1,1,1)>>> (mydat=0x13034a0000)
at kernel.cu:5
5       int id = threadIdx.x;
(cuda-gdb) n
7       double *X = &shr[(id * 6)];
(cuda-gdb) p id
$1 = 0
(cuda-gdb) p id * 6
$2 = 0
(cuda-gdb) n
8       double *Y = &shr[(id * 6) + 3];
(cuda-gdb) p (id * 6) + 3
$3 = 3
(cuda-gdb) n
10      X[0] = mydat[0];
(cuda-gdb) n
11      X[1] = mydat[1];    
(cuda-gdb) n
12      X[2] = mydat[2];    
(cuda-gdb) n
13      Y[0] = mydat[3];
(cuda-gdb) n 
14      Y[1] = mydat[4];
(cuda-gdb) n
15      Y[2] = mydat[5];
(cuda-gdb) p X
$4 = (@generic double * @register) 0x1000000
(cuda-gdb) p X[0]
$5 = 0
(cuda-gdb) p X[1]
$6 = 1
(cuda-gdb) p Y[0]
$7 = 3
(cuda-gdb) p Y[1]
$8 = 4
(cuda-gdb) n
18      __syncthreads();    
(cuda-gdb) n
22      for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
(cuda-gdb) n
23          result += X[i] + Y[i];
(cuda-gdb) p i
$9 = 0
(cuda-gdb) p X[0] 
$10 = 0
(cuda-gdb) p X[i]
Error: Failed to read global memory at address 0x0 on device 0 sm 0 warp 0 lane 0 (error=7).
```

Comment: ?? this: `extern __shared__ shr[];` is not valid CUDA C/C++.

Comment: Sorry @RobertCrovella I typed this a little hastily last night - in the code that is producing the problem it is declared as  `extern __shared__ double shr[];` I am updating the OP to reflect this.

Comment: In general, it will be very hard to explain runtime behaviour of code we haven't been shown. Your indexing calculations for `X` and `Y` are clearly incorrect (Y for thread id = 0 will be the same as X for thread id = 1), but what else might be going wrong is impossible to say without an [MCVE]. If you can't provide one, I doubt you will get an answer

Comment: It's also unclear where your instruction pointer is in the various `cuda-gdb` commands you have shown above.  I assume you set a breakpoint in the kernel code somewhere.  But depending on where you are in the code, even when compiled with `-G`, variables can be in scope or out of scope, and attempting to access out-of-scope variables (e.g. local variables) will give inconsistent results.  A complete code and a complete gdb session showing exactly what you did might be necessary to explain anything.

Comment: Sounds reasonable - I will make a working example today.

Comment: OP updated with working code

Comment: All you are seeing is compiler optimisation effects. The `__syncthreads` call is the last valid instruction in your kernel. The entire summation loop is optimised away by the compiler. So do you have an actual question here?

Comment: As a general rule, you shouldn't spend much time thinking about, or working on, or using tools to analyze code that does not modify any global state.

Comment: Thank you, you actually led me to the answer. I have been writing several lines and checking with the debugger as I go. At one point I was not seeing the right values from the loop, but I did not realize that until the loop had some global effect on the calculation, it would be optimized out and thus I suppose not viewable in the debugger. Writing the next few lines anyways so that it included the result of the loop helped me find the real issue. @talonmies did you use a software tool to figure out the "last instruction" or did you simply know by inspection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All that is happening here is that you are stepping through source instructions which have not actually been compiled into the running kernel. The variables you are trying to inspect have already gone out of scope and the debugger can no longer show them to you.

This is due to aggressive optimisation in the device code compiler. In your example, the summation loop doesn't produce an output which effects a write to global or shared memory, so the compiler just eliminates it. When stepping through the optimised code, the source debugger tried its best to show a 1:1 relationship between source and execution, but it isn't always possible, and this is the somewhat confusing result you are seeing.

You can confirm this for yourself by compiling your kernel code to PTX using nvcc and inspecting the code:

```
    // .globl   _Z9my_kernelPd
.visible .entry _Z9my_kernelPd(
    .param .u64 _Z9my_kernelPd_param_0
)
{
    .reg .b32   %r<3>;
    .reg .f64   %fd<7>;
    .reg .b64   %rd<6>;


    ld.param.u64    %rd1, [_Z9my_kernelPd_param_0];
    cvta.to.global.u64  %rd2, %rd1;
    mov.u32     %r1, %tid.x;
    mul.lo.s32  %r2, %r1, 6;
    mul.wide.s32    %rd3, %r2, 8;
    mov.u64     %rd4, shr;
    add.s64     %rd5, %rd4, %rd3;
    ld.global.nc.f64    %fd1, [%rd2];
    ld.global.nc.f64    %fd2, [%rd2+8];
    ld.global.nc.f64    %fd3, [%rd2+16];
    ld.global.nc.f64    %fd4, [%rd2+24];
    ld.global.nc.f64    %fd5, [%rd2+32];
    ld.global.nc.f64    %fd6, [%rd2+40];
    st.shared.f64   [%rd5], %fd1;
    st.shared.f64   [%rd5+8], %fd2;
    st.shared.f64   [%rd5+16], %fd3;
    st.shared.f64   [%rd5+24], %fd4;
    st.shared.f64   [%rd5+32], %fd5;
    st.shared.f64   [%rd5+40], %fd6;
    bar.sync    0;
    ret;
}
```

You can see the last PTX instruction is `bar`, which is the instruction which the `__syncthreads()` device function emits. The loop for summation is not present.

If I modify you source like this:

```
__global__ void my_kernel2(double *mydat, double *out) {
    extern __shared__ double shr[];
    int id = threadIdx.x;

    double *X = &shr[(id * 6)];
    double *Y = &shr[(id * 6) + 3];

    X[0] = mydat[0];
    X[1] = mydat[1];        
    X[2] = mydat[2];        
    Y[0] = mydat[3];
    Y[1] = mydat[4];
    Y[2] = mydat[5];


    __syncthreads();        

    double result;

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        result += X[i] + Y[i];
    }
    *out = result;
}
```

so that `result` is now stored to global memory and compile it to PTX:

```
.visible .entry _Z10my_kernel2PdS_(
    .param .u64 _Z10my_kernel2PdS__param_0,
    .param .u64 _Z10my_kernel2PdS__param_1
)
{
    .reg .b32   %r<3>;
    .reg .f64   %fd<20>;
    .reg .b64   %rd<8>;


    ld.param.u64    %rd3, [_Z10my_kernel2PdS__param_0];
    ld.param.u64    %rd2, [_Z10my_kernel2PdS__param_1];
    cvta.to.global.u64  %rd4, %rd3;
    mov.u32     %r1, %tid.x;
    mul.lo.s32  %r2, %r1, 6;
    mul.wide.s32    %rd5, %r2, 8;
    mov.u64     %rd6, shr;
    add.s64     %rd1, %rd6, %rd5;
    ld.global.f64   %fd1, [%rd4];
    ld.global.f64   %fd2, [%rd4+8];
    ld.global.f64   %fd3, [%rd4+16];
    ld.global.f64   %fd4, [%rd4+24];
    ld.global.f64   %fd5, [%rd4+32];
    ld.global.f64   %fd6, [%rd4+40];
    st.shared.f64   [%rd1], %fd1;
    st.shared.f64   [%rd1+8], %fd2;
    st.shared.f64   [%rd1+16], %fd3;
    st.shared.f64   [%rd1+24], %fd4;
    st.shared.f64   [%rd1+32], %fd5;
    st.shared.f64   [%rd1+40], %fd6;
    bar.sync    0;
    ld.shared.f64   %fd7, [%rd1];
    ld.shared.f64   %fd8, [%rd1+24];
    add.f64     %fd9, %fd7, %fd8;
    add.f64     %fd10, %fd9, %fd11;
    ld.shared.f64   %fd12, [%rd1+8];
    ld.shared.f64   %fd13, [%rd1+32];
    add.f64     %fd14, %fd12, %fd13;
    add.f64     %fd15, %fd10, %fd14;
    ld.shared.f64   %fd16, [%rd1+16];
    ld.shared.f64   %fd17, [%rd1+40];
    add.f64     %fd18, %fd16, %fd17;
    add.f64     %fd19, %fd15, %fd18;
    cvta.to.global.u64  %rd7, %rd2;
    st.global.f64   [%rd7], %fd19;
    ret;
}
```

You can see that the (urolled) loop is now present in the PTX, and the debugger behaviour should be closer to what you expect if you were to try it.

As suggested in comments, you shouldn't ever spend time trying to analyse any code which doesn't change block or global state, because of the complications caused by compiler optimisation.